# Converting date from cookie string format to mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql, php-carbon

I have a string which is like date of the cookie `Thursday, 25-Dec-1975 14:15:16 EST`. I have a string which is in this format `25-Dec-1975`. I want to convert it to mysql date format(2017-04-27). I tried the below way but it didn't work out.

```
    $get_date = "25-Dec-2016";
    $converted = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$get_date);
    echo $converted;
```

My input is in string type. Is there any other direct method to convert above in the mysql date format ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP's date` function

`date("Y-m-d",strtotime("25-Dec-2016"));`